# Printing lines in a text file given line numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop, user-defined-functions

I am having trouble with a while loop statement for the question below. This is for a txt.file.

> 'Write a program that allows the user to navigate through the lines of text in any text file. The program prompts the user for a filename and copies the lines of text from the file into a list. The program then prints the number of lines in the file and prompts the user for a line number. Actual line numbers range from 1 to the number of lines in the file. If the input is 0, the program quits. Otherwise, the program prints the text in that line number.'

Please see my code.

```
enterfile = input("Enter the file name: ")
file = open(enterfile, 'r')
linecount = 0
for line in file:
    linecount = linecount + 1
print("The number of lines in this txt. file is", linecount)
linenum = 0
while True:
num = int(input("Please enter a line number or press 0 to quit: "))
if num >=1 and num <= linecount:
    file = open(enterfile, 'r')
    for lines in file:
        linenum = linenum + 1
        if linenum == num:
            print(lines)
else:
    if num == 0:
        print("Thanks for using the program")
        break
```

When I run the program, the line number does not print after I enter a line number.

Obviously, I am not using the while loop correctly here. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Can I possibly use a def function here?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you debug your program?

Comment: You can read the file into a list using `list_of_lines = list(file)`. Then `linecount = len(list_of_lines)` and you can get a requested line by using `list_of_lines[num-1]` (remember lists start at 0)

Comment: @JeroenHeier No, I did not. Not sure how to do that. I am just a beginner.

Comment: You are not resetting linenum between runs. You should have `linenum = 0` just before the `for` loop if you want to keep doing it that way

Comment: Have a look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial). Learning debugging the code you have made is very important.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Thank you for the tip. The requested line is now printing. However, it is only working for every other number that is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move line `linenum = 0` inside the `While True:` loop.

The `linenum` variable must be reset to 0 (`linenum = 0`) when the program re-enters the loop. Otherwise the `linenum` variable will always keep being incremented and have a value that is greater than `num` and will never trigger the if statement to print the line at that number.

**Your code** with `linenum = 0` in the loop:

```
enterfile = input("Enter the file name: ")
file = open(enterfile, 'r')
linecount = 0

for line in file:
    linecount = linecount + 1

print("The number of lines in this txt. file is", linecount)

while True:
    linenum = 0

    num = int(input("Please enter a line number or press 0 to quit: "))
    if num >=1 and num <= linecount:
        file = open(enterfile, 'r')
        for lines in file:
            linenum = linenum + 1
            if linenum == num:
                print(lines)
    else:
        if num == 0:
            print("Thanks for using the program")
            break
```

---

**Alternative method:**

```
enterfile = input("Enter the file name: ")

with open(enterfile) as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

print("The number of lines in this txt. file is", len(lines))

while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter a line number or press 0 to quit: "))

    if num > 0 and num < len(lines) + 1:
        print(lines[num - 1]) 
    elif num == 0:
        print('Thanks for using the program.')
        break
```

Comment: Btw, `linecount = sum(1 for _ in file)` is a shorter way to get that

Comment: @empty: Thanks! I made the edits and it is working. However, it appears that the program is only printing the line for every other number that is entered.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the tip. I will try this in the program.

Comment: @cricket_007 He mentioned that he is new to python so I'm just using his code to help him understand his mistake. A very simple fix would be to just move his `linenum = 0` variable initialization inside his while loop.

Comment: @empty Maybe simple fix, but still seems like too much code for what's being asked

Comment: a.. Your code is working fine with that simple fix. However, for a more efficient way of writing this script, take a look at @cricket_007 's answer. Once you have your lines in a list you can simply just get the index from the user's input and print the string at that index from the list in a while loop.

Comment: @a.. Don't forget to "accept" an answer by clicking the check mark button at the top left corner of an answer block.

Comment: @empty ... Just did. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you missed the first step of the assignment after the input

> copies the lines of text from the file into a list

With that, you would have

```
with open(enterfile) as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
# continue on from here
```

Now, forget you even have a file, you can use `len(lines)` and `lines[number-1]` to get the total lines and a specific line, respectively

Answer (score 1):

use readlines() function return a list that containing the lines then print index value according to user input.

```
file = input("Enter the file name: ")
text_file = open(file, "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
print (len(lines))
while True:
    linenumber = int(input("Please enter a line number or press 0 to quit:  "))
    if linenumber == 0:
        print("Thanks for using the program")
        break
    elif 1 <= linenumber <= len(lines) :
      print (lines[linenumber- 1])
    else:
        print("Please enter valid line number")
text_file.close()
```

Comment: That'll include a trailing newline character at the end of each line in the list, though

Answer (score 0):

Put `linenum = 0` inside the while loop and your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Polished version:

```
enterfile = input("Enter the input file name: ")
file = open(enterfile, 'r')
linecount = 0
for line in file:
    linecount = linecount + 1
print("The file has",linecount,"lines.")
while True:
    linenum = 0
    num = int(input("Enter a line number [0 to quit]: "))
    if num >=1 and num <= linecount:
        file = open(enterfile, 'r')
        for lines in file:
            linenum = linenum + 1
            if linenum == num:
                print(num,":",lines)
    elif num == 0:
        break
    else:
        if num!= linecount:
            print("ERROR: line number must be less than",linecount)
```